# Copying/Pasting nodes between Object and World shader editor modes

Tags: materials, shaders, world

Recently, I have been trying to work a lot more in the world nodes for shading, and cannot figure out how would I copy a large node group I have for an object into the world editor.
Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Crtl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Crtl+V</kbd>.

You can also make a Group out of your selection, with <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, then reuse it with Add Node / Group / NameOfYourGroup.